# How to change background color of active button when i am using bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Currently i am using the following: 
with this the normal background color and hover state color are changed but when i click a button it becomes light blue(i.e. active state)
what is it that i am missing?

```css
.btn-primary{
    font-family: TimeBurner;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #232323;
    border-color: #222222;
}
.btn-primary:hover{
    background-color: #111111;
    border-color: #000000;
}
.btn-primary.active, .btn-primary:active{
    background-color: #111111;
 border-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="getRatePerKGAir()">
          Rate/KG Air
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="getRatePerKGSurface()">
          Rate/KG Surface
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="getSalienceAir()">
          Salience Air
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="getSalienceSurface()">
          Salience Surface
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In firefox press, F12, then select your button, and you will see the CSS applied to your button, and the lines concerned in your css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target `.btn-primary:focus` too. It is `.btn-primary:focus` that is responsible for coloring the buttons `#3276b1` after click :

```css
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active {
    background-color: #111111;
    border-color: #000000;
}
```

then it works -> **http://jsfiddle.net/y5jo73wo/**

Answer (score 0):

in your CSS code add this one

```
.btn-primary:active:hover{
    background-color: red;
    border-color: red;}
```

Comment: can you please create fiddle link

Comment: still my issue wasn't resolved....needed to add :focus as well.
thanks for your time though :)